# Linq query for joining three tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, visual-studio

I have three tables table1 (main table), table2, table3.

- table1 contains table1Id
- table2 and table3 contain table2Id, table2RoleId, table3Id, table3RoleId.

Also the same value of table1Id, more than one record in table2Id and table3Id but the table2RoleId's and table3RoleId's are different.

I want to join table1 with table2 and table3 to display like
Table2RoleId and Table3RoleId has to display according to the Table1Id

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: lets take an example:table1Id:1,table2Id:1,table2RoleId:ab,table2Id:1,table2RoleId:cd,table3Id:1,table3RoleId:gh,table3Id:1,table2RoleId:ij.Now display table2RoleId and table3RoleId depending upon table1Id.

Answer (score 0):

i'm ignore the content of your question and will show you sample left join in linq

```
var result = from x in table1 join y in table2 
             on x.tableId1 equals y.tableId1 
             join z in table3 on x.tableId1 equals z.tableId1 
             Select new {// your return fields}
```

Comment: I i have only one tableId1 value then it is working fine but If i have more than one table1Id's it is displaying all RoleId's in all the records.

Comment: can you show what you have written that your query is working for one `tableId1` value

Comment: var table2query = (from j in table2 join s in table1 on j.table2Id equals  s.table1Id
select new
{
                            industryid = j.table1Id,
                            industryusrid = s.table2RoleID,
                    }).ToList();

similarly I have written for table3

Comment: you can use group by to group your records by table1id's and after that join your table.